# How can I prove that for any $A, B$ if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$, then $(C-A)\cup (B-A)\subseteq C$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> How can I prove that for any $A, B$ if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$, then $(C-A)\cup (B-A)\subseteq C$?

I've been working on this question and I haven't really made much progress with it.  I know that I can rewrite it as $(C \cap A^c) \cup (B\cap A^c)$. I'm pretty sure that if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$ then $A \subseteq C$. If this is the case then wouldn't $(C \cap A^c) = \emptyset$ and $(B \cap A^c) = \emptyset$ or am not understanding something with set theory? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Rewrite each statement as an implication in memberships.

Comment: Consider $A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{1,2,3\}$. We have $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$. But the complement $A^c$ of $A$ *with respect to $C$* (as it's important to stress what the complement is in respect to) is $\{2,3\}$, so $C\cap A^c=\{2,3\}$ and $B\cap A^c=\{2\}$.

Comment: $A \subset C$ means everything in $A$ is in $C$.  $C\setminus A$ means all the stuff in $C$ that isn't in $A$.  If $A$ is in $C$ then $C\setminus A$ is all the stuff in $C$ that isn't in $A$.  That needn't be empty.  Maybe you are confusing $C \setminus A$ with $A \setminus C$? Setminus is *not* commutative. $A \setminus C$ is all the stuff in $A$ that is not in $C$, but *everything* in $A$ is in $C$ so $A\setminus C = \emptyset$.  But $C\setminus A$ is just... $C \setminus $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply: by definition, $C-A\subseteq Cˆ$ and $B-A\subseteq B$. Further, $B\subseteq C$...

Answer (score 1):

It's not the case that $X \subseteq Y$ implies $Y-X = \emptyset$.  Indeed if $X = \{0\}$ and $Y = \{0,1\}$ then $Y - X = \{1\}$.

We do have, however, that $X \subseteq Y$ implies $Y - X \subseteq Y$.  Applying this to what you have so far, conclude that $C- A \subseteq C$ and $B - A \subseteq B \subseteq C$.  Hence $(C-A) \cup (B-A) \subseteq C$ too.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\in (B-A)\cup (C-A)$, either $x\in B-A$ or $x\in C-A$ (or both). For every $x\in B-A$, $x\in B$ hence $x\in C$. For every $x\in C-A$, obviously $x\in C$. Hence if $x\in (B-A)\cup (C-A)$, surely $x\in C$. By definition, this means that it is a subset of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw Venn Diagrams. This should be obvious.

[image]

Now just prove it with Element chasing or definitions or whatever you like.